# how to use Absolute time range grafana when not exist timestamp column

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, grafana

this is my_table on **postgresql** db. I have not specific column for timestamp or datetime.
I want to draw this table on **Grafana**. To display the traffic according to Grafana **absolute time range**.
Now with this table structure how can I do this?

| year | month | day | hour | traffic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 11 | 18 | 06 | 6546546 |
| 2023 | 11 | 17 | 07 | 7987654 |

Comment: What do you call an absolute time range, and why do you think it's important to this question?

Comment: Why don't you convert you separate date component into a proper timestamp (inside a query, that is)?

Comment: Per [Date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html): `select make_timestamp(2023, 11, 18, 6, 0, 0); 2023-11-18 06:00:00`.  So in your case `make_timestamp(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you gain by storing the time units in separate columns, but the absence of a timestamp is probably annoying in more than just this case - consider altering the table with: `timestamp_column TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS (make_timestamp(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0)) STORED`  and also consider indexing that column.